# Найти все пробелы между словами

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В текущих строках мне нужно через регулярку найти все пробелы между словами, которые находятся в кавычках

```regex
text['Sh a p es']
text['Sh a p es']
text[' Sha pes']
text['   ']
```

Я написал такое выражение `/text\['(\s*)'\]/gm`, но оно подбирает только те строки, в которых идут одни пробелы подряд

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```
(?:\G(?!^)|text\[')[^']*?\K\s+(?=[^']*'])
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/6KzRGi/1).

**Подробности**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|text\[')` - конец предыдущего совпадения или текст `text['`
- `[^']*?` - ноль и более (но как можно меньше) символов, отличных от `'`
- `\K` - оператор, очищающий буфер текущего совпадения
- `\s+` - один и более пробельных символов
- `(?=[^']*'])` - сразу после текущей позиции должны быть ноль и более символов, отличных от `'`, а потом текст `']`.